# rust jni environment test setup on mac

Tags: macos, rust, java-native-interface, jnienv

I am using crate `jni = { version = "0.20.0", features = ["invocation"] }` and was trying to setup a test that could run JNI stuff.

my boot code is as follows

```
        let jvm_args = InitArgsBuilder::new()
            .version(JNIVersion::V8)
            .option("-Xcheck:jni")
            .build()
            .unwrap();

        let jvm = JavaVM::new(jvm_args).unwrap();
        let _guard = jvm.attach_current_thread().unwrap();
        let env = jvm.get_env().unwrap();
        JavaClasses::init(&env);
```

I cant seem to get this running on mac, as when the IDE `RustRover` lauches the binary, it always have problems finding the dynamic linked libs, complaining

```
Error: could not find libjava.dylib
Failed to GetJREPath()
```

tried to lookup the `rpath` names, seems nothing returned

```
➜  blaze git:(tests) ✗ otool -l xxxlaze/target/debug/deps/blaze_tests-b310798913eec8e4 | ag -C 5 LC_RPATH       
➜  blaze git:(tests) ✗
```

I did try to set them though in build.rs

```
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", libjvm_path.display());
    // println!("cargo:rustc-link-arg=-Wl,-rpath={}", libjvm_path.display());
    println!("cargo:rustc-env=LD_LIBRARY_PATH={}", libjvm_path.display());
```

Comment: The java_locator crate uses the `/usr/libexec/java_home` command to locate the JVM. Is your Mac not set up properly? Setting JAVA_HOME at runtime also works, which is a convention in the Java community as a whole.

Comment: @Botje I didn't use that, jni crate has build script to locate the path, but seems only build time. runtime still failed to load the libs.  I do have the `/usr/libexec/java_home` but I guess since this is only the rust test binary, not necessarily linked all the java essentials

Comment: Did you not enable the `java_locator` feature in your JNI crate then?

Comment: Hmm, `java_locator` seems to be on by default if you select `invocation`... You will need to debug your application and step into `JavaVM::new` and the various functions it calls from the `java_locator` crate

Answer (score 0):

I send up doing something similar to JNI crate, with a `build.rs` build script to locate jvm path like this (exactly the same as the version in JNI crate)

```
fn find_libjvm<S: AsRef<Path>>(path: S) -> Option<PathBuf> {
    let walker = walkdir::WalkDir::new(path).follow_links(true);

    for entry in walker {
        let entry = match entry {
            Ok(entry) => entry,
            Err(_e) => continue,
        };

        let file_name = entry.file_name().to_str().unwrap_or("");

        if file_name == EXPECTED_JVM_FILENAME {
            return entry.path().parent().map(Into::into);
        }
    }

    None
}
```

then the following is the key, setting the `rpath` which is used to locate the dylib.

```
println!("cargo:rustc-link-arg=-Wl,-rpath,{}", libjvm_path.display());
```

this makes the tests run.